# Geolocation API coordinates returns NaN for Mozilla Firefox 66

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I'm using Geolocation API to get my current coordinates and it works for Chrome but when I'm using Firefox version 66.0.3 it returns NaN for both latitude and longitude.

FYI. I also tried testing it in a lower version of Firefox, version 64.0 to be exact and it works just fine.

Please see my codes below.

```
function init()
{
  if(navigator.geolocation)
  {
    var geoOptions = { enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge : 300000 };

     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_pos, error_pos, geoOptions);
  }
}

function show_pos(positions)
{
  console.log(positions.coords.latitude, positions.coords.longitude);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works correctly on FF 66.0.2. Does the Position object returned by the function look correct otherwise?

Comment: Works fine for me in FF 66.0.3; Did you try `console.log(positions)`? Any extensions that might interfere?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick response. I've tried console.log(positions); and it returns Coordinates { latitude: NaN, longitude: NaN, ... }. Just to be on the same page @ChrisG you mean browser extensions right?

Comment: Yes. Hm, weird. Looks like geolocation is blocked somehow? Since it works for me, the issue must be specific to your machine/browser. Can you test your code on another machine?